# I just create an ArrayList now I need to test

Tags: java

This is my `Arraylist` I'm having trouble how to make a new class to check if my methods work.

Any help will be useful I need to know how to make a start my new class .

I create a class but I keep getting it wrong.
Do I have to extend it our in my new class am only?

Any assistance will be greatly useful.

```
public class MyArray<E extends Comparable<E>> {

// No other data fields necessary.

    private E[] data;
    private int size;

    public MyArray(int size) {
        this.data = (E[]) (new Comparable[size]);
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(E item) {
        if (size == data.length)
            resize();
        data[size] = item;
        size++;
    }

    private void resize() {
        int len = data.length * 2;
        E[] temp = (E[]) new Comparable[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            temp[i] = data[i];

        data = temp;
    }

    public boolean contains(E item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (data[i].equals(item))
                return true;
        }

        return false; // not found
    }

    public void delete(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        for (int i = index + 1; i < size; i++) {
            data[i - 1] = data[i];
        }
        size--;
    }

    public boolean delete(E item) {
        if (item == null)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (data[i].equals(item)) {
                delete(i); // delete at index i
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;// not found

    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and then have a look at [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: this is how i start but i cant seem to make it work .    public class MyArrayListTester extends MyArray {
 
 public MyArrayListTester(int size) {
  super(size);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // add the integers to the array
  MyArray arr = new MyArray(0);

  arr.add(1);

 }

}

Comment: use `new MyArray(10);` instead of `new MyArray(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Since your class is defined with generics (the E), you have to provide an actual type for E. Actually, it should work pretty much like ArrayList class.

```
MyArray<String> a = new MyArray<String>(10);
a.add("Foo");
a.add("Bar");
```